# Call for R in MATLAB by using command 'R CMD BATCH ou.txt'

Tags: r, matlab

I have configured R and managed to set up environment variables. In CMD I can execute the code `R CMD BATCH ou.txt`. However in MATLAB when I tried to execute `system('R CMD BATCH ou.txt')`, I see the error “'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.” How can I run R from within MATLAB?

Comment: Did you restart MATLAB after setting the environment variables?

Comment: in a pinch it might be worth trying `system('/path/to/R CMD BATCH ou.txt')`